# For Loop to parse through csv files in a directory with the same header and after each looped file print new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, for-loop

For Loop to parse through csv files in a directory with the same header and after each looped file print new columns

As seen with the code below it combines all files in a directory vertically. I want it to combine horizontally after each file to have multiple rows

```
import os
import pandas as pd
#RUN THIS AFTER MAKING ALL THE CSV FILEs
dfmaster = pd.DataFrame()
directory = "/content/drive/My Drive/"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    fullpath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath) and fullpath.endswith(".csv"):
        dfchild = pd.read_csv(fullpath)
        select_cols = ['var1', 'var2']
        #define columns you want to explort
        dfmaster = dfchild[select_cols]
        #####Problem here, After each file print to two new columns I don't know what to input here
    print(dfmaster.reset_index(drop=True))
    dfmaster.to_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Subsurface_A.csv", index=False)
```

So Summary: The current for loop combines columns vertically. I want to learn how to do this horizontally as in if this were excel

instead of columns A B with all the data. I want columns A B per file  to place next to each other so to have columns A B C D E F G....

Sorry in advanced I don't know coding jargon. If a mod sees this please rephrase if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty df outside of your loop, then continuously concat along the columns each loop:

```
#empty df
finaldf = pd.Dataframe()
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    fullpath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath) and fullpath.endswith(".csv"):
        dfchild = pd.read_csv(fullpath)
        select_cols = ['obs', 'temperature']
        #define columns you want to explort
        dfmaster = dfchild[select_cols]

        #new line
        finaldf = pd.concat([finaldf, dfmaster],axis = 1)


    print(finaldf.reset_index(drop=True))
    finaldf.to_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Subsurface_A.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! concat seems very useful. I should definitely have the manual of each module I am using up while coding since my working knowledge of the modules used is still of low competence at the moment. A very simple and elegant fix keeping the previous code I started.